# Can a visiter change jQuery code on their browser (Datatables)

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am new to PHP & jQuery and learning day-by-day. I have come across a question which I just need to make sure is ok before proceeding any further.

I am using Datatables within a PHP script and pulling the data from ajax in Json format. I need to have a button within an action column and the only way I can really see of doing this is by the following

```
   var oTable
    $(document).ready(function () {

        oTable = $('#epdatatable').DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: 'ajax-user.php',
                dataSrc: '',
            },
            columns: [
                {"data": 'firstname'},
                {"data": 'lastname'},
                {"data": 'email'},
                {
                    "className": 'options dt-body-right',
                    "data": null,
                    "width": '0.5%',
                    "render": function (data, row, type, full, meta) {

                        if(data.active == 0){
                            return '<a href="senduserinvite.php?uid=' + data.uid + '"><button style="padding: 2px 20px;" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary pull-right"> Sent Invite</button></a>';
                        }else{
                            return '<a href="viewuser.php?uid=' + data.uid + '"><button style="padding: 2px 20px;" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary pull-right"> View</button></a>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]

        });

    });
```

My question is, can an online visitor just edit an entry such as data.active == 0 to 1 and change the buttons?

If this is the case, are there any other ways of building a button or dropdown buttons via PHP, server-side preferably?

Thanks

Comment: The user can change anything on the client. They can change the JavaScript, they can change the HTML, they can change the CSS. Anything that needs to be protected has to be done on the server.

Comment: What threat are you trying to protect against? They can simply put `viewuser.php?uid=123` in the browser's address bar, they don't need to change the JavaScript.

Comment: you could always check the server-side value of "active" before running the server side action related to the buttons...in other words, validate what you get from the client side.

Comment: Sorry, so that was a quick example of what I had at that point but my concern was that if I wanted to later create a datatable and have a multi-usage ajax file so I could pass things in like the table and then the current user ID to pull relational user (sub-user). So basically from what I see above, a client side user could simply change the user ID in the browser and pull other users data from it?